# Parallax effect not working in RelativeLayout with CoordinateLayout android

Tags: android, parallax, android-coordinatorlayout

I have a `relativelayout` that needs to give `parallax effect` . I am using `CoordinateLayout` for this.

I `relativelayout` is not giving me the `parallax effect`. I used NestedScrollView for scrolling.

**What the layout file contains**

1 CoordinatorLayout

1 DrawerLayout

1 AppBarLayout

2 Toolbar

1 ViewPager

my code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
                app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">


                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/linear_profile"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">


                    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                        android:id="@+id/toolbar_home"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="56dp"
                        android:background="@color/cyan_dark"
                        android:visibility="visible"
                        app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
                        app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
                        app:layout_collapseMode="pin">

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/img_back"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                            android:paddingRight="30dp"
                            android:paddingTop="10dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_back"
                            android:visibility="visible" />


                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center">

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/tv_header_tittle"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                                android:maxLength="50"
                                android:padding="5dp"
                                android:text="Change Password"
                                android:textColor="@color/white"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/txt_large" />

                            <com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator
                                android:id="@+id/circle_indicator"
                                android:layout_width="100dp"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_below="@+id/tv_header_tittle"
                                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                                android:layout_gravity="center"
                                android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                                android:visibility="visible"
                                app:fillColor="@color/white"
                                app:pageColor="@color/cyan_dark"
                                app:strokeColor="@color/white" />
                        </RelativeLayout>


                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/img_glob"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="right"
                            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                            android:paddingLeft="30dp"
                            android:paddingRight="10dp"
                            android:paddingTop="10dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_home_globe"
                            android:visibility="visible" />

                    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:id="@+id/relative_profile_hotot"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="250dp"
                        android:padding="0dp"
                        app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                        android:visibility="visible">

                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:id="@+id/rel_profile"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:visibility="visible"
                            >


                            <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
                                android:id="@+id/img_profile_cover"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                                android:src="@drawable/im_default_cover" />

                            <ImageView
                                android:id="@+id/img_edit_cover"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                                android:padding="20dp"
                                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                                android:src="@drawable/btn_profile_edit" />


                            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                                android:id="@+id/relative_profile_footer"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="40dp"
                                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                                android:background="@color/album_name_bg">

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/tv_profile_name"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_gravity="left"
                                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                                    android:paddingTop="5dp"
                                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                                    android:textSize="@dimen/txt_small"
                                    tools:text="Karan Asrani" />

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/tv_profile_location"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_home_place"
                                    android:drawablePadding="5dp"
                                    android:drawableRight="@drawable/btn_profile_edit"
                                    android:paddingRight="5dp"
                                    android:paddingTop="5dp"
                                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                                    android:textSize="@dimen/txt_small"
                                    tools:text="Paris France" />


                            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


                            <RelativeLayout
                                android:id="@+id/relative_profile_pic"
                                android:layout_width="70dp"
                                android:layout_height="70dp"
                                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                                android:layout_marginBottom="30dp">

                                <camera.CircledNetworkImageView
                                    android:id="@+id/img_profile_pic"
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                    android:src="@drawable/im_home_profile_default"
                                    app:layout_anchor="@id/appbar" />


                                <ImageView
                                    android:id="@+id/img_edit_profile"
                                    android:layout_width="15dp"
                                    android:layout_height="15dp"
                                    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/img_profile_pic"
                                    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/img_profile_pic"
                                    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/img_profile_pic"
                                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                                    android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                                    android:src="@drawable/btn_profile_edit"
                                    android:visibility="visible" />


                                <ImageView
                                    android:id="@+id/img_profile_pic_status"
                                    android:layout_width="18dp"
                                    android:layout_height="18dp"
                                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                                    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                                    android:src="@drawable/ic_home_red_circle"
                                    android:visibility="gone" />


                            </RelativeLayout>


                        </RelativeLayout>


                        <ProgressBar
                            android:id="@+id/prg_dialog"
                            android:layout_width="60dp"
                            android:layout_height="60dp"
                            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                            android:visibility="gone" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/txt_loading"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/prg_dialog"
                            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                            android:textColor="@color/text_color"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/txt_large"
                            android:visibility="gone" />
                    </RelativeLayout>
                </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"></android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

            </LinearLayout>


        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv_navigation"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/bucket_header"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:background="@drawable/splashscreen_bg"
        android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:visibility="visible"></android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: I think that you can only apply behavior to the direct children of `CoordinatorLayout`. Of course, you can add the xml attribute `app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"` to any view, but it's just going to get ignored if the view which applies it is not a direct child.

Comment: any way to get this done ?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to accomplish, but let me try again and let me step back a little bit because I think I got some things wrong. So it seems that the real problem is that your `RelativeLayout` is not a direct child of the `CollapsingToolbarLayout`. Maybe you could try refactoring your layout hierarchy in such a way where `RelativeLayout` **is** a direct child of the `CollapsingToolbarLayout`. I'm afraid I don't have any more suggestions or solutions besides this one...

Comment: This is what I tried . Still not the expected output :(

Comment: Did you got the answer ? I am facing same issue..